# How to create file config for Log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I want logging object when he adding in database:

```
Queue<Proposal> proposals = ...;

log.info(proposals.peek());

channelToDatabase.ingection(proposals.poll());
```

My `Proposal` object:

```
public class Proposal {
    /**
     * Header of Proposal.
     */
    private String header;
    /**
     * Author of Proposal.
     */
    private String author;
    /**
     * Create date of Proposal.
     */
    private Timestamp create;
    /**
     * Link to Proposal page.
     */
    private String ulrPropose;
    /**
     * Account recruiter.
     */
    private String urlRecruiter;

    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setNickname(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreateTime() {
        return create;
    }

    public void setCreate(Timestamp create) {
        this.create = create;
    }

    public String getUlrPropose() {
        return ulrPropose;
    }

    public void setUlrPropose(String ulrPropose) {
        this.ulrPropose = ulrPropose;
    }

    public String getUrlRecruiter() {
        return urlRecruiter;
    }

    public void setUrlRecruiter(String urlRecruiter) {
        this.urlRecruiter = urlRecruiter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Proposal{" +
                "header='" + header + '\'' +
                ", author='" + author + '\'' +
                ", create=" + create +
                ", ulrPropose='" + ulrPropose + '\'' +
                ", urlRecruiter='" + urlRecruiter + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I want get in my info log something like:

```
header, ulrPropose, time_addition, nickname, author, urlRecruiter
```

Something like select from my database but in log.

I needed config file `log4j.properties` for this. Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It in fact has little relation with log4j.

What you should modify is the toString() function Proposal , change that to the format you want. something like:

```
return header + "," + author ...
```

And you can choose a log4j.properties on the internet  at random, it will work. Only to remember change the ConversionPattern with only  "%m%n", so you will not get unnecessary information.